# How to plot outliers with regard to unique ids

Tags: pandas, plot

I have `item_code` column in my data and another column, `sales`, which represents sales quantity for the particular item.

**The data can have a particular item id many times.** There are other columns tell apart these entries.

**I want to plot only the outlier sales** for each item (because data has thousands of different item ids, plotting every entry can be difficult).

Since I'm very new to this, what is the right way and tool to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use pandas. You should choose a method to detect outliers, but I have an example for you:

If you want to get outliers for all sales (not in groups), you can use apply with function (example - lambda function) to have outliers indexes.

```
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.DataFrame({'item_id': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
                  'sales': [0, 2, 30, 3, 30, 30, 55]})

df[df.apply(lambda x: np.abs(x.sales - df.sales.mean()) / df.sales.std() > 1, 1)
           ].set_index('item_id').plot(style='.', color='red')
```

In this example we generated data sample and search indexes of points what are more then mean / std + 1 (you can try another method). And then just plot them where y is count of sales and x is item id. This method detected points 0 and 55. If you want search outliers in groups, you can group data before.

```
df.groupby('item_id').apply(lambda data: data.loc[
    data.apply(lambda x: np.abs(x.sales - data.sales.mean()) / data.sales.std() > 1, 1)
]).set_index('item_id').plot(style='.', color='red')
```

In this example we have points 30 and 55, because 0 isn't outlier for group where item_id = 1, but 30 is.

Is it what you want to do? I hope it helps start with it.